# SyntaxError running AssignDomainToField_management function for ArcMap

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, syntaxerror

I'm trying to set a domain for a feature class field using the below syntax and IDLE keeps giving me an invalid syntax error with no specifics. I can't find which line it's rejecting to even begin troubleshooting.

What is wrong with the code?

```py
import arcpy

try:
    # Set the workspace (to avoid having to type in the full path to the data every time). Update foe each new file.
    arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.8\ROBERT FILES\EXTRACTION WORKING FOLDER\ROBERT_WORKING_EXTRACTION.gdb\TransportationGroundCrv_AddFieldTest"
 
    # Set parameters
    domName = "Road_Class_Types"
    gdb = "ROBERT_WORKING_EXTRACTION.gdb"
    inFeatures = "ROBERT_WORKING_EXTRACTION.gdb\TransportationGroundCrv_AddFieldTest"
    inField = "AP030_Road_Class"
 
    # Process: Create the coded value domain
    arcpy.CreateDomain_management("ROBERT_WORKING_EXTRACTION.gdb", Road_Class_Types, "Road Class types per LTDS schema", "TEXT", "CODED")
    
    #Store all the domain values in a dictionary with the domain code as the "key" and the 
    #domain description as the "value" (domDict[code])
    domDict = {"Class 5 Road": "Class 5 Road - Unimproved (ZI016_ROC = 1), Fair Weather (ZI016_WTC = 2), one (1) or two lanes (2) or less, (LTN = 1 or 2, FCO =7", \
               "Class 4 Road": "Class 4 Road - Flexible Pavement (ZI016_ROC = 3), Limited All-weather (ZI016_WTC = 4), one (1) or two lanes (2) or less, (LTN = 2), FCO =7", \
               "Class 1 Highway": "Class 1 Highway - Rigid Pavement (ZI016_ROC = 7), Divided Highway, All Weather (ZI016_WTC = 1), three lanes (3), (LTN = 3), FCO = 5 or 6", \
               "Class 2 Highway": "Class 2 Highway - Rigid Pavement (ZI016_ROC = 7), Divided Highway, All Weather (ZI016_WTC = 1), two lanes (2), (LTN = 2), FCO = 5 or 6", \
               "Class 3 Highway": "Class 3 Highway - Rigid Pavement (ZI016_ROC = 7), Undivided Highway, All Weather (ZI016_WTC = 1), one (1) or two (2) or less, (LTN = 2), FCO = 7", \
               "Superhighway": "Superhighway - Rigid Pavement (ZI016_ROC = 7), Divided Highway, All Weather (ZI016_WTC = 1), four or more lanes (4), (LTN>=4),FCO = 5 or 6", \
               "noInformation" : "noInformation"}
    
    # Process: Add valid types to the domain
    #use a for loop to cycle through all the domain codes in the dictionary
    for code in domDict:        
        arcpy.AddCodedValueToDomain_management(gdb, domName, code, domDict[code])
    
    # Process: Constrain the material value of distribution mains
    arcpy.AssignDomainToField_management(inFeatures, inField, domName)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an open `try` block with no closing block; removing that should fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

The problem is possibly down to this line

```
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.8\ROBERT FILES\EXTRACTION WORKING FOLDER\ROBERT_WORKING_EXTRACTION.gdb\TransportationGroundCrv_AddFieldTest"
```

You are using window file path syntax so you need to say its raw text, all you need to do is put an `r` in front of the string so something like:

```
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Temp\Data"
```

Otherwise the \ character, an escape character in python is interpreted as you wanting to put in special characters, a classic would by c:\temp, the \t is interpreted as a TAB character, so the file path c:[tab]emp makes no sense.

Comment: Okay thank you. I added that and am still getting the same unspecified "invalid" syntax error.